# Python 3+: Container to incrementally add items for speed

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm scraping many pages of a website for some data that i'm putting into a dictionary with lists as the values, ie

```
data = {'A':[1,2,3], 'B':['a','b','c'], 'C': [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]}
```

Each page will add an item to each list, so after 4 pages, the dictionary will look like this:

```
data = {'A':[1,2,3,4], 'B':['a','b','c','d'], 'C': [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]}
```

I know there are a few ways to build the data as i crawl each page, but I'm just wondering what the best container would be for this?
Keeping in mind that i will be writing the data to a .csv file at the completion of the crawl.

My current thinking is to build up the dictionary and use `DictWriter()` or load into a pandas dataframe and use `to_csv()`

Is there a better container for faster performance?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpandas%5D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that loading the data into a dictionary and then converting this to a Pandas dataframe has made it easier to write to csv.

I found this easier to conceptualize what i was doing.